# Is talking with a girl in a bed online zina - please don’t skip

Tags: sharia, zina, halal-haram

So once some time ago I was playing a PG game and I went in a game where it was a watermark and there were houses surrounding it. I went inside one of the houses and saw another girl character in the bed (I was ignorant at the time) so I went and also lied down on the bed and we chatted online by the way all of this was online and there was no illegal sex Involved and you can’t go naked in the game and I don’t think I said anything bad I don’t remember this as well. To summarise I was allying an online game and saw a girl in a bed and I sat in the same bed and we talked (no sex and no masturbating involved) is this zina? I am very doubtful about this and I personally don’t know however I really need an answer.

Answer (score -1):

AOA, Please read the linked post for clarification.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/3013/is-zinaa-intercourse-only

In my humble opinion, ISLAMQA is a site where Experts of sharia guide according to the situation, not a layman. Would recommend for such issues.

Jazak Allah

Comment: Please quote the relevant portion from the linked article which answers this question.

Comment: Sorry but that website doesn't feature paragraph linking that's why I am pasting it( the end of second paragraph)

Allaah has decreed for every son of Adam his share of zinaa, and there is no way to escape from it. The zinaa of the eye is a glance, the zinaa of the tongue is speaking, and the zinaa of the mind is wishing and hoping; then the private part either acts upon this or it does not. (Reported by al-Bukhaari, 11/26; Muslim, 4/2046).

Comment: Zina has different types and level,sexual intercourse is one of them.

Answer (score -2):

Really, zina is unlawful sexual intercourse. Not something that can happen in virtual sutuation. Zina is physical sin not virtual sin. Even if you lay with her in bed(Game) it is not zina. You must know the meaning of "zina".

Not every thing that happened between non mahram is zina only sexual intercourse is zina.

Comment: Zina which carries the Hadd punishment is definitely only intercourse, however the word Zina is also applied to other acts which do not carry the Hadd. See the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/79/17).